# How to generate GIF 256 colors palette

Tags: c#, colors, gif, color-palette

I need to create in C# a matrix of 16 X 16 clickable rectangles, then filling each rectangle with a color from a 256 colors palette (GIF).

I just need help to create a simple class to generate 256 colors.

[image: Palette of 256 colors]

Comment: Why *generate* it? Just find a nice palette you like and hard-code the values. An array of 256 values isn't that much.

Comment: Is there a way to generate it automatically?

Comment: You *can* generate a 256-color palette easily (it's just a few nested loops), but it will probably not be as nice as a hard-coded palette.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will do a hard-coded palette as you said. ... Have a nice day!

Answer (score 35):

Couple nested loops might actually cause a bunch of clashing. You want maximally distinct colors. Here's like 1022 I generated. Took like a month to run them through CIE-LAB de2000.

The first 256 will look like:

[image]

These even start to clash. 256 moderately different colors is hard to do even with brute force and the best color distance algorithms on the planet.

Static lists are the way to go here. But, things will still clash with that many colors.

[image: 1024 color]

```
public static final String[] indexcolors = new String[]{
        "#000000", "#FFFF00", "#1CE6FF", "#FF34FF", "#FF4A46", "#008941", "#006FA6", "#A30059",
        "#FFDBE5", "#7A4900", "#0000A6", "#63FFAC", "#B79762", "#004D43", "#8FB0FF", "#997D87",
        "#5A0007", "#809693", "#FEFFE6", "#1B4400", "#4FC601", "#3B5DFF", "#4A3B53", "#FF2F80",
        "#61615A", "#BA0900", "#6B7900", "#00C2A0", "#FFAA92", "#FF90C9", "#B903AA", "#D16100",
        "#DDEFFF", "#000035", "#7B4F4B", "#A1C299", "#300018", "#0AA6D8", "#013349", "#00846F",
        "#372101", "#FFB500", "#C2FFED", "#A079BF", "#CC0744", "#C0B9B2", "#C2FF99", "#001E09",
        "#00489C", "#6F0062", "#0CBD66", "#EEC3FF", "#456D75", "#B77B68", "#7A87A1", "#788D66",
        "#885578", "#FAD09F", "#FF8A9A", "#D157A0", "#BEC459", "#456648", "#0086ED", "#886F4C",
        "#34362D", "#B4A8BD", "#00A6AA", "#452C2C", "#636375", "#A3C8C9", "#FF913F", "#938A81",
        "#575329", "#00FECF", "#B05B6F", "#8CD0FF", "#3B9700", "#04F757", "#C8A1A1", "#1E6E00",
        "#7900D7", "#A77500", "#6367A9", "#A05837", "#6B002C", "#772600", "#D790FF", "#9B9700",
        "#549E79", "#FFF69F", "#201625", "#72418F", "#BC23FF", "#99ADC0", "#3A2465", "#922329",
        "#5B4534", "#FDE8DC", "#404E55", "#0089A3", "#CB7E98", "#A4E804", "#324E72", "#6A3A4C",
        "#83AB58", "#001C1E", "#D1F7CE", "#004B28", "#C8D0F6", "#A3A489", "#806C66", "#222800",
        "#BF5650", "#E83000", "#66796D", "#DA007C", "#FF1A59", "#8ADBB4", "#1E0200", "#5B4E51",
        "#C895C5", "#320033", "#FF6832", "#66E1D3", "#CFCDAC", "#D0AC94", "#7ED379", "#012C58",
        "#7A7BFF", "#D68E01", "#353339", "#78AFA1", "#FEB2C6", "#75797C", "#837393", "#943A4D",
        "#B5F4FF", "#D2DCD5", "#9556BD", "#6A714A", "#001325", "#02525F", "#0AA3F7", "#E98176",
        "#DBD5DD", "#5EBCD1", "#3D4F44", "#7E6405", "#02684E", "#962B75", "#8D8546", "#9695C5",
        "#E773CE", "#D86A78", "#3E89BE", "#CA834E", "#518A87", "#5B113C", "#55813B", "#E704C4",
        "#00005F", "#A97399", "#4B8160", "#59738A", "#FF5DA7", "#F7C9BF", "#643127", "#513A01",
        "#6B94AA", "#51A058", "#A45B02", "#1D1702", "#E20027", "#E7AB63", "#4C6001", "#9C6966",
        "#64547B", "#97979E", "#006A66", "#391406", "#F4D749", "#0045D2", "#006C31", "#DDB6D0",
        "#7C6571", "#9FB2A4", "#00D891", "#15A08A", "#BC65E9", "#FFFFFE", "#C6DC99", "#203B3C",
        "#671190", "#6B3A64", "#F5E1FF", "#FFA0F2", "#CCAA35", "#374527", "#8BB400", "#797868",
        "#C6005A", "#3B000A", "#C86240", "#29607C", "#402334", "#7D5A44", "#CCB87C", "#B88183",
        "#AA5199", "#B5D6C3", "#A38469", "#9F94F0", "#A74571", "#B894A6", "#71BB8C", "#00B433",
        "#789EC9", "#6D80BA", "#953F00", "#5EFF03", "#E4FFFC", "#1BE177", "#BCB1E5", "#76912F",
        "#003109", "#0060CD", "#D20096", "#895563", "#29201D", "#5B3213", "#A76F42", "#89412E",
        "#1A3A2A", "#494B5A", "#A88C85", "#F4ABAA", "#A3F3AB", "#00C6C8", "#EA8B66", "#958A9F",
        "#BDC9D2", "#9FA064", "#BE4700", "#658188", "#83A485", "#453C23", "#47675D", "#3A3F00",
        "#061203", "#DFFB71", "#868E7E", "#98D058", "#6C8F7D", "#D7BFC2", "#3C3E6E", "#D83D66",
        "#2F5D9B", "#6C5E46", "#D25B88", "#5B656C", "#00B57F", "#545C46", "#866097", "#365D25",
        "#252F99", "#00CCFF", "#674E60", "#FC009C", "#92896B", "#1E2324", "#DEC9B2", "#9D4948",
        "#85ABB4", "#342142", "#D09685", "#A4ACAC", "#00FFFF", "#AE9C86", "#742A33", "#0E72C5",
        "#AFD8EC", "#C064B9", "#91028C", "#FEEDBF", "#FFB789", "#9CB8E4", "#AFFFD1", "#2A364C",
        "#4F4A43", "#647095", "#34BBFF", "#807781", "#920003", "#B3A5A7", "#018615", "#F1FFC8",
        "#976F5C", "#FF3BC1", "#FF5F6B", "#077D84", "#F56D93", "#5771DA", "#4E1E2A", "#830055",
        "#02D346", "#BE452D", "#00905E", "#BE0028", "#6E96E3", "#007699", "#FEC96D", "#9C6A7D",
        "#3FA1B8", "#893DE3", "#79B4D6", "#7FD4D9", "#6751BB", "#B28D2D", "#E27A05", "#DD9CB8",
        "#AABC7A", "#980034", "#561A02", "#8F7F00", "#635000", "#CD7DAE", "#8A5E2D", "#FFB3E1",
        "#6B6466", "#C6D300", "#0100E2", "#88EC69", "#8FCCBE", "#21001C", "#511F4D", "#E3F6E3",
        "#FF8EB1", "#6B4F29", "#A37F46", "#6A5950", "#1F2A1A", "#04784D", "#101835", "#E6E0D0",
        "#FF74FE", "#00A45F", "#8F5DF8", "#4B0059", "#412F23", "#D8939E", "#DB9D72", "#604143",
        "#B5BACE", "#989EB7", "#D2C4DB", "#A587AF", "#77D796", "#7F8C94", "#FF9B03", "#555196",
        "#31DDAE", "#74B671", "#802647", "#2A373F", "#014A68", "#696628", "#4C7B6D", "#002C27",
        "#7A4522", "#3B5859", "#E5D381", "#FFF3FF", "#679FA0", "#261300", "#2C5742", "#9131AF",
        "#AF5D88", "#C7706A", "#61AB1F", "#8CF2D4", "#C5D9B8", "#9FFFFB", "#BF45CC", "#493941",
        "#863B60", "#B90076", "#003177", "#C582D2", "#C1B394", "#602B70", "#887868", "#BABFB0",
        "#030012", "#D1ACFE", "#7FDEFE", "#4B5C71", "#A3A097", "#E66D53", "#637B5D", "#92BEA5",
        "#00F8B3", "#BEDDFF", "#3DB5A7", "#DD3248", "#B6E4DE", "#427745", "#598C5A", "#B94C59",
        "#8181D5", "#94888B", "#FED6BD", "#536D31", "#6EFF92", "#E4E8FF", "#20E200", "#FFD0F2",
        "#4C83A1", "#BD7322", "#915C4E", "#8C4787", "#025117", "#A2AA45", "#2D1B21", "#A9DDB0",
        "#FF4F78", "#528500", "#009A2E", "#17FCE4", "#71555A", "#525D82", "#00195A", "#967874",
        "#555558", "#0B212C", "#1E202B", "#EFBFC4", "#6F9755", "#6F7586", "#501D1D", "#372D00",
        "#741D16", "#5EB393", "#B5B400", "#DD4A38", "#363DFF", "#AD6552", "#6635AF", "#836BBA",
        "#98AA7F", "#464836", "#322C3E", "#7CB9BA", "#5B6965", "#707D3D", "#7A001D", "#6E4636",
        "#443A38", "#AE81FF", "#489079", "#897334", "#009087", "#DA713C", "#361618", "#FF6F01",
        "#006679", "#370E77", "#4B3A83", "#C9E2E6", "#C44170", "#FF4526", "#73BE54", "#C4DF72",
        "#ADFF60", "#00447D", "#DCCEC9", "#BD9479", "#656E5B", "#EC5200", "#FF6EC2", "#7A617E",
        "#DDAEA2", "#77837F", "#A53327", "#608EFF", "#B599D7", "#A50149", "#4E0025", "#C9B1A9",
        "#03919A", "#1B2A25", "#E500F1", "#982E0B", "#B67180", "#E05859", "#006039", "#578F9B",
        "#305230", "#CE934C", "#B3C2BE", "#C0BAC0", "#B506D3", "#170C10", "#4C534F", "#224451",
        "#3E4141", "#78726D", "#B6602B", "#200441", "#DDB588", "#497200", "#C5AAB6", "#033C61",
        "#71B2F5", "#A9E088", "#4979B0", "#A2C3DF", "#784149", "#2D2B17", "#3E0E2F", "#57344C",
        "#0091BE", "#E451D1", "#4B4B6A", "#5C011A", "#7C8060", "#FF9491", "#4C325D", "#005C8B",
        "#E5FDA4", "#68D1B6", "#032641", "#140023", "#8683A9", "#CFFF00", "#A72C3E", "#34475A",
        "#B1BB9A", "#B4A04F", "#8D918E", "#A168A6", "#813D3A", "#425218", "#DA8386", "#776133",
        "#563930", "#8498AE", "#90C1D3", "#B5666B", "#9B585E", "#856465", "#AD7C90", "#E2BC00",
        "#E3AAE0", "#B2C2FE", "#FD0039", "#009B75", "#FFF46D", "#E87EAC", "#DFE3E6", "#848590",
        "#AA9297", "#83A193", "#577977", "#3E7158", "#C64289", "#EA0072", "#C4A8CB", "#55C899",
        "#E78FCF", "#004547", "#F6E2E3", "#966716", "#378FDB", "#435E6A", "#DA0004", "#1B000F",
        "#5B9C8F", "#6E2B52", "#011115", "#E3E8C4", "#AE3B85", "#EA1CA9", "#FF9E6B", "#457D8B",
        "#92678B", "#00CDBB", "#9CCC04", "#002E38", "#96C57F", "#CFF6B4", "#492818", "#766E52",
        "#20370E", "#E3D19F", "#2E3C30", "#B2EACE", "#F3BDA4", "#A24E3D", "#976FD9", "#8C9FA8",
        "#7C2B73", "#4E5F37", "#5D5462", "#90956F", "#6AA776", "#DBCBF6", "#DA71FF", "#987C95",
        "#52323C", "#BB3C42", "#584D39", "#4FC15F", "#A2B9C1", "#79DB21", "#1D5958", "#BD744E",
        "#160B00", "#20221A", "#6B8295", "#00E0E4", "#102401", "#1B782A", "#DAA9B5", "#B0415D",
        "#859253", "#97A094", "#06E3C4", "#47688C", "#7C6755", "#075C00", "#7560D5", "#7D9F00",
        "#C36D96", "#4D913E", "#5F4276", "#FCE4C8", "#303052", "#4F381B", "#E5A532", "#706690",
        "#AA9A92", "#237363", "#73013E", "#FF9079", "#A79A74", "#029BDB", "#FF0169", "#C7D2E7",
        "#CA8869", "#80FFCD", "#BB1F69", "#90B0AB", "#7D74A9", "#FCC7DB", "#99375B", "#00AB4D",
        "#ABAED1", "#BE9D91", "#E6E5A7", "#332C22", "#DD587B", "#F5FFF7", "#5D3033", "#6D3800",
        "#FF0020", "#B57BB3", "#D7FFE6", "#C535A9", "#260009", "#6A8781", "#A8ABB4", "#D45262",
        "#794B61", "#4621B2", "#8DA4DB", "#C7C890", "#6FE9AD", "#A243A7", "#B2B081", "#181B00",
        "#286154", "#4CA43B", "#6A9573", "#A8441D", "#5C727B", "#738671", "#D0CFCB", "#897B77",
        "#1F3F22", "#4145A7", "#DA9894", "#A1757A", "#63243C", "#ADAAFF", "#00CDE2", "#DDBC62",
        "#698EB1", "#208462", "#00B7E0", "#614A44", "#9BBB57", "#7A5C54", "#857A50", "#766B7E",
        "#014833", "#FF8347", "#7A8EBA", "#274740", "#946444", "#EBD8E6", "#646241", "#373917",
        "#6AD450", "#81817B", "#D499E3", "#979440", "#011A12", "#526554", "#B5885C", "#A499A5",
        "#03AD89", "#B3008B", "#E3C4B5", "#96531F", "#867175", "#74569E", "#617D9F", "#E70452",
        "#067EAF", "#A697B6", "#B787A8", "#9CFF93", "#311D19", "#3A9459", "#6E746E", "#B0C5AE",
        "#84EDF7", "#ED3488", "#754C78", "#384644", "#C7847B", "#00B6C5", "#7FA670", "#C1AF9E",
        "#2A7FFF", "#72A58C", "#FFC07F", "#9DEBDD", "#D97C8E", "#7E7C93", "#62E674", "#B5639E",
        "#FFA861", "#C2A580", "#8D9C83", "#B70546", "#372B2E", "#0098FF", "#985975", "#20204C",
        "#FF6C60", "#445083", "#8502AA", "#72361F", "#9676A3", "#484449", "#CED6C2", "#3B164A",
        "#CCA763", "#2C7F77", "#02227B", "#A37E6F", "#CDE6DC", "#CDFFFB", "#BE811A", "#F77183",
        "#EDE6E2", "#CDC6B4", "#FFE09E", "#3A7271", "#FF7B59", "#4E4E01", "#4AC684", "#8BC891",
        "#BC8A96", "#CF6353", "#DCDE5C", "#5EAADD", "#F6A0AD", "#E269AA", "#A3DAE4", "#436E83",
        "#002E17", "#ECFBFF", "#A1C2B6", "#50003F", "#71695B", "#67C4BB", "#536EFF", "#5D5A48",
        "#890039", "#969381", "#371521", "#5E4665", "#AA62C3", "#8D6F81", "#2C6135", "#410601",
        "#564620", "#E69034", "#6DA6BD", "#E58E56", "#E3A68B", "#48B176", "#D27D67", "#B5B268",
        "#7F8427", "#FF84E6", "#435740", "#EAE408", "#F4F5FF", "#325800", "#4B6BA5", "#ADCEFF",
        "#9B8ACC", "#885138", "#5875C1", "#7E7311", "#FEA5CA", "#9F8B5B", "#A55B54", "#89006A",
        "#AF756F", "#2A2000", "#576E4A", "#7F9EFF", "#7499A1", "#FFB550", "#00011E", "#D1511C",
        "#688151", "#BC908A", "#78C8EB", "#8502FF", "#483D30", "#C42221", "#5EA7FF", "#785715",
        "#0CEA91", "#FFFAED", "#B3AF9D", "#3E3D52", "#5A9BC2", "#9C2F90", "#8D5700", "#ADD79C",
        "#00768B", "#337D00", "#C59700", "#3156DC", "#944575", "#ECFFDC", "#D24CB2", "#97703C",
        "#4C257F", "#9E0366", "#88FFEC", "#B56481", "#396D2B", "#56735F", "#988376", "#9BB195",
        "#A9795C", "#E4C5D3", "#9F4F67", "#1E2B39", "#664327", "#AFCE78", "#322EDF", "#86B487",
        "#C23000", "#ABE86B", "#96656D", "#250E35", "#A60019", "#0080CF", "#CAEFFF", "#323F61",
        "#A449DC", "#6A9D3B", "#FF5AE4", "#636A01", "#D16CDA", "#736060", "#FFBAAD", "#D369B4",
        "#FFDED6", "#6C6D74", "#927D5E", "#845D70", "#5B62C1", "#2F4A36", "#E45F35", "#FF3B53",
        "#AC84DD", "#762988", "#70EC98", "#408543", "#2C3533", "#2E182D", "#323925", "#19181B",
        "#2F2E2C", "#023C32", "#9B9EE2", "#58AFAD", "#5C424D", "#7AC5A6", "#685D75", "#B9BCBD",
        "#834357", "#1A7B42", "#2E57AA", "#E55199", "#316E47", "#CD00C5", "#6A004D", "#7FBBEC",
        "#F35691", "#D7C54A", "#62ACB7", "#CBA1BC", "#A28A9A", "#6C3F3B", "#FFE47D", "#DCBAE3",
        "#5F816D", "#3A404A", "#7DBF32", "#E6ECDC", "#852C19", "#285366", "#B8CB9C", "#0E0D00",
        "#4B5D56", "#6B543F", "#E27172", "#0568EC", "#2EB500", "#D21656", "#EFAFFF", "#682021",
        "#2D2011", "#DA4CFF", "#70968E", "#FF7B7D", "#4A1930", "#E8C282", "#E7DBBC", "#A68486",
        "#1F263C", "#36574E", "#52CE79", "#ADAAA9", "#8A9F45", "#6542D2", "#00FB8C", "#5D697B",
        "#CCD27F", "#94A5A1", "#790229", "#E383E6", "#7EA4C1", "#4E4452", "#4B2C00", "#620B70",
        "#314C1E", "#874AA6", "#E30091", "#66460A", "#EB9A8B", "#EAC3A3", "#98EAB3", "#AB9180",
        "#B8552F", "#1A2B2F", "#94DDC5", "#9D8C76", "#9C8333", "#94A9C9", "#392935", "#8C675E",
        "#CCE93A", "#917100", "#01400B", "#449896", "#1CA370", "#E08DA7", "#8B4A4E", "#667776",
        "#4692AD", "#67BDA8", "#69255C", "#D3BFFF", "#4A5132", "#7E9285", "#77733C", "#E7A0CC",
        "#51A288", "#2C656A", "#4D5C5E", "#C9403A", "#DDD7F3", "#005844", "#B4A200", "#488F69",
        "#858182", "#D4E9B9", "#3D7397", "#CAE8CE", "#D60034", "#AA6746", "#9E5585", "#BA6200"
    };
```

- Thanks R. Wang in comments. I lost two colors formatting the data, and he found them in an ocean of colors.

I notice that the linked image is hue sorted, might be a fluke, but toss in a sort and:

Sorted:
[image]

```
#B88183
#922329
#5A0007
#D7BFC2
#D86A78
#FF8A9A
#3B000A
#E20027
#943A4D
#5B4E51
#B05B6F
#FEB2C6
#D83D66
#895563
#FF1A59
#FFDBE5
#CC0744
#CB7E98
#997D87
#6A3A4C
#FF2F80
#6B002C
#A74571
#C6005A
#FF5DA7
#300018
#B894A6
#FF90C9
#7C6571
#A30059
#DA007C
#5B113C
#402334
#D157A0
#DDB6D0
#885578
#962B75
#A97399
#D20096
#E773CE
#AA5199
#E704C4
#6B3A64
#FFA0F2
#6F0062
#B903AA
#C895C5
#FF34FF
#320033
#DBD5DD
#EEC3FF
#BC23FF
#671190
#201625
#F5E1FF
#BC65E9
#D790FF
#72418F
#4A3B53
#9556BD
#B4A8BD
#7900D7
#A079BF
#958A9F
#837393
#64547B
#3A2465
#353339
#BCB1E5
#9F94F0
#9695C5
#0000A6
#000035
#636375
#00005F
#97979E
#7A7BFF
#3C3E6E
#6367A9
#494B5A
#3B5DFF
#C8D0F6
#6D80BA
#8FB0FF
#0045D2
#7A87A1
#324E72
#00489C
#0060CD
#789EC9
#012C58
#99ADC0
#001325
#DDEFFF
#59738A
#0086ED
#75797C
#BDC9D2
#3E89BE
#8CD0FF
#0AA3F7
#6B94AA
#29607C
#404E55
#006FA6
#013349
#0AA6D8
#658188
#5EBCD1
#456D75
#0089A3
#B5F4FF
#02525F
#1CE6FF
#001C1E
#203B3C
#A3C8C9
#00A6AA
#00C6C8
#006A66
#518A87
#E4FFFC
#66E1D3
#004D43
#809693
#15A08A
#00846F
#00C2A0
#00FECF
#78AFA1
#02684E
#C2FFED
#47675D
#00D891
#004B28
#8ADBB4
#0CBD66
#549E79
#1A3A2A
#6C8F7D
#008941
#63FFAC
#1BE177
#006C31
#B5D6C3
#3D4F44
#4B8160
#66796D
#71BB8C
#04F757
#001E09
#D2DCD5
#00B433
#9FB2A4
#003109
#A3F3AB
#456648
#51A058
#83A485
#7ED379
#D1F7CE
#A1C299
#061203
#1E6E00
#5EFF03
#55813B
#3B9700
#4FC601
#1B4400
#C2FF99
#788D66
#868E7E
#83AB58
#374527
#98D058
#C6DC99
#A4E804
#76912F
#8BB400
#34362D
#4C6001
#DFFB71
#6A714A
#222800
#6B7900
#3A3F00
#BEC459
#FEFFE6
#A3A489
#9FA064
#FFFF00
#61615A
#FFFFFE
#9B9700
#CFCDAC
#797868
#575329
#FFF69F
#8D8546
#F4D749
#7E6405
#1D1702
#CCAA35
#CCB87C
#453C23
#513A01
#FFB500
#A77500
#D68E01
#B79762
#7A4900
#372101
#886F4C
#A45B02
#E7AB63
#FAD09F
#C0B9B2
#938A81
#A38469
#D16100
#A76F42
#5B4534
#5B3213
#CA834E
#FF913F
#953F00
#D0AC94
#7D5A44
#BE4700
#FDE8DC
#772600
#A05837
#EA8B66
#391406
#FF6832
#C86240
#29201D
#B77B68
#806C66
#FFAA92
#89412E
#E83000
#A88C85
#F7C9BF
#643127
#E98176
#7B4F4B
#1E0200
#9C6966
#BF5650
#BA0900
#FF4A46
#F4ABAA
#000000
#452C2C
#C8A1A1
```

Comment: There are only 1022 colors in the `indexcolors`. The 3rd and 4th color from the 6th row (from bottom left) are missing. It should be something like `#576E4A, #7F9EFF` after `#2A2000` according to the provided image

Comment: Yeah, must have lost those two during processing the text. Since the whole algorithm took something like a month to run, I would reuse the output I think a later version of this took those missing values to help pre-process the last two (since I lost two) and those will have to be deprecated. I used them on a similar question. --- That's an amazing catch. Thankfully I encoded to a lossless png so those values there actually are going to be spot on. This is the first comment I'd like to assign a bounty to.

Comment: There is no justice in the world, the research effort gone into this and only 20 upvotes!